# In macOS, how to reload two Safari browsers in Split Screen mode via AppleScript?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I have an AppleScript that will reload my safari browser every x amount of seconds:

`activate application "Safari"
repeat
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
    delay (5)
end repeat`

As I use the "Split Screen" feature within macOS, I want to expand this code to refresh both Safari browsers.

Comment: Are you running two separate instances of _Safari_, or a single instance with two _Safari_ browser windows open ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a better way to reload the current *Safari* window:

```
tell application "Safari" to tell the front document to set its URL to its URL
```

To do this for multiple open windows:

```
tell application "Safari" to repeat with D in every document
    set D's URL to D's URL
end repeat
```

Stick that in a repeat loop, add the necessary delay, and you'll have continuously-refreshing browser windows:

```
tell application "Safari" to repeat while document 2 exists
    repeat with D in every document
        set D's URL to D's URL
    end repeat
    delay 5
end repeat
```